# How to find two edges that come from the same node?

Tags: r, network-programming, bioinformatics

I am trying to perform a network analysis.

Currently I have a metabolic network, which has metabolites as nodes and gene (enzyme) information on each edges.

My goal is to find pairs of genes that are not on the same pathway.
In other words, I'm trying to collect gene pairs that originate from a single metabolite node. These two genes (enzymes) would then diffuse to a different direction from that metabolite.

I have trying hard coding, but it seems to be too laborious and I thought maybe there would be a package or function in R that somebody have made before.

Can anyone suggest something?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.